# How to get column value in Excel based on other value results?

Tags: excel

I need to get value based on other value result.

For example: column A1 returns 24, so I need to get value from A24.

It should be simple but I can't find how to do it!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You have not taken much time to explain the question you are trying to answer. Are you trying to write a formula or are you using VB? If you are using a formula, take a look at `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: I'm trying to write a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want hard-coded column A with a variable row based on the value of cell A1, you would end up with a formula that says:
`=INDIRECT(CONCAT("A", A1))`

Comment: exactly what I need, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` is a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function), so to be avoided where possible. Simply:

`=INDEX(A:A,A1)`